# Tiva C FFT Library

Tags: c, embedded, fft, fftw, kissfft

I'm carrying on a new embedded systems project that analyse input frequency and get the coefficients of the frequencies and produces some information based on this information.

I will be using Tiva C TM4C Microcontroller, and I've done heaps of search to find any compatible C language FFT library and I've failed.

I actually found some general Libraries like FFTW and KissFFT, But I've failed to use them as I think they are very complicated and couldn't manage to find code examples or even a user manual or so.

So Can anyone help me finding the good Library I'm looking for? 
Or even a how-to-use manual for FFTW/KissFFT libraries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801158/fft-in-a-single-c-file

Comment: The FFT library [here](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/research/prod/?id=510) has less than a hundred lines of code in a single C-file. There is also a simple code example.

Answer (score 0):

FFTW provides some helpful tutorials (See: http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Tutorial.html#Tutorial)

For your Microcontroller (CortexM4) exists with the "CMSIS DSP library"(just google it) a very powerful and well documented DSP library that is espacially designed for embedded systems. But it has a comparable interface complexity than the FFTW library.

If you want an easy interface and if you have lots of calculation time, you can write your own DFT calculation by using the naive approach implementing the 
[DFT formula](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/d/2/0/d20809d6889f48f67fd37a77206f83f2.png).