# Need help understanding this line in an FFT algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, fft, dft

In my program I have a function that performs the fast Fourier transform. I know there are very good implementations freely available, but this is a learning thing so I don't want to use those. I ended up finding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37729648/12553917) with the following implementation (it originated from the Italian entry for the FFT):

```
void transform(complex<double>* f, int N) //
{
  ordina(f, N);    //first: reverse order
  complex<double> *W;
  W = (complex<double> *)malloc(N / 2 * sizeof(complex<double>));
  W[1] = polar(1., -2. * M_PI / N);
  W[0] = 1;
  for(int i = 2; i < N / 2; i++)
    W[i] = pow(W[1], i);
  int n = 1;
  int a = N / 2;
  for(int j = 0; j < log2(N); j++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
      if(!(k & n)) {
        complex<double> temp = f[k];
        complex<double> Temp = W[(k * a) % (n * a)] * f[k + n];
        f[k] = temp + Temp;
        f[k + n] = temp - Temp;
      }
    }
    n *= 2;
    a = a / 2;
  }
  free(W);
}
```

I've made a lot of changes by now but this was my starting point. One of the changes I made was to not cache the twiddle factors, because I decided to see if it's needed first. Now I've decided I do want to cache them. The way this implementation seems to do it is it has this array `W` of length `N/2`, where every index `k` has the value [image: twiddle factor]. What I don't understand is this expression:

`W[(k * a) % (n * a)]`

Note that `n * a` is always equal to `N/2`. I get that this is supposed to be equal to [image: another twiddle factor], and I can see that [image: equivalence], which this relies on. I also get that modulo can be used here because the twiddle factors are cyclic. But there's one thing I don't get: this is a length-N DFT, and yet only `N/2` twiddle factors are ever calculated. Shouldn't the array be of length N, and the modulo should be by N?

Comment: Essentially what it does 2 lines later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But there's one thing I don't get: this is a length-N DFT, and yet only N/2 twiddle factors are ever calculated. Shouldn't the array be of length N, and the modulo should be by N?

The twiddle factors are equally spaced points on the unit circle, and there is an even number of points because N is a power-of-two. After going around half of the circle (starting at 1, going counter clockwise above the X-axis), the second half is a repeat of the first half but this time it's below the X-axis (the points can be reflected through the origin). That is why `Temp` is subtracted the second time. That subtraction is the negation of the twiddle factor.